# How to do a groupBy by a given column but still keep all the rows of the original DataFrame?

Tags: pyspark

I want to do a groupBy and aggregate by a given column in PySpark but I still want to keep all the rows from the original DataFrame.

For example lets say we have the following DataFrame and we want to do a max on the "value" column then we would get the result below.

Original DataFrame

```
+--+-----+
|id|value|
+--+-----+
| 1|    1|
| 1|    2|
| 2|    3|
| 2|    4|
+--+-----+
```

Result

```
+--+-----+---+
|id|value|max|
+--+-----+---+
| 1|    1|  2|
| 1|    2|  2|
| 2|    3|  4|
| 2|    4|  4|
+--+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function

```
 df.withColumn('max', max('value').over(Window.partitionBy('id'))).show()


+---+-----+---+
| id|value|max|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|    1|  2|
|  1|    2|  2|
|  2|    3|  4|
|  2|    4|  4|
+---+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply by joining aggregated dataframe with original dataframe

```
aggregated_df = (
    df
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(F.max('value').alias('max'))
)

max_value_df = (
    df
    .join(aggregated_df, 'id')
)
```